# export and import inventory warehouse in a table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with 4 column in sql (key ID):

```
ID  Items  Import  Export  
1    A1      1333   0       
2    A1      0     368     
3    A1      0     252      
4    A1      1965   0       
5    A1      0     162     
6    A1      0     551     
7    A1      0     69
```

I want calculate inventory ware in a row.But not the results as expected.
You can help me get the results as below? With column Inventory

```
ID  Items  Import  Export  Inventory
1    A1      1333   0       1333
2    A1      0     368      965
3    A1      0     252      713
4    A1      1965   0       2678
5    A1      0     162      2516
6    A1      0     551      1965
7    A1      0     69       1896
```

This is my code:

```
Select ID,
(A.Invent + Import-Sum(Export)) as Inventory 
From MyColumn,
(
Select Top 1 (Import - Export) as Invent 
From MyColumn 
Where Items in ('A1')
) as A 

Where Items in ('A1') 

Group by 
A.Invent,
Import,ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being 2008 you're missing the **sum() over**, however there is another option

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([ID] int,[Items] varchar(50),[Import] int,[Export] int)
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'A1',1333,0)
,(2,'A1',0,368)
,(3,'A1',0,252)
,(4,'A1',1965,0)
,(5,'A1',0,162)
,(6,'A1',0,551)
,(7,'A1',0,69)

Select A.*
      ,B.* 
 from @YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( 
              Select Inventory = sum(Import-Export) 
               From  @YourTable 
               Where Items=A.Items and ID<=A.ID
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Items   Import  Export  Inventory
1   A1      1333    0       1333
2   A1      0       368     965
3   A1      0       252     713
4   A1      1965    0       2678
5   A1      0       162     2516
6   A1      0       551     1965
7   A1      0       69      1896
```

Comment: @MrTrung Happy to help

Answer (score 0):

Using a join
Also window function but this is not available in 2008

```
declare @T table (id int identity primary key, import int, export int);
insert into @T (import, export) values 
       (1333,  0)
     , (0, 368)
     , (0, 252)
     , (1965, 0)
     , (0, 162)
     , (0, 551)
     , (0 , 69);

select t1.id, t1.import, t1.export 
     , sum(t2.import - t2.export) AS inven
from @T t1
join @T t2 
  on t2.id <= t1.id 
group by t1.id, t1.import, t1.export 
order by t1.id

select * 
     , sum(import - export) over (order by t.id) as inven 
from @T t;

id          import      export      inven
----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           1333        0           1333
2           0           368         965
3           0           252         713
4           1965        0           2678
5           0           162         2516
6           0           551         1965
7           0           69          1896
```

Comment: I used the code above but it error: "Incorrect syntax near 'order'."

Comment: @MrTrung Works on my compute.  Sorry I could not be of more help.